# div in percent with margin? Total 100%

Tags: html, css

Want to make a grid that looks like this where div/section is in percent. Margin is the same everywhere. 
http://www.ladda-upp.se/bilder/giefekcmgwmnx/

The following code works if I put margin to 1px, but I want to use margin 1em or around 10px. How do I do that?

html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="default.css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="box small"></div>
    <div class="box small"></div>
    <div class="box small"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="box small"></div>
    <div class="box large"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.box {
    height:50px;
    margin:1em;
    background:#000;
    float:left;
}
.small {
    width:33%;
}
.large {
    width:66%;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Why not use another `DIV` inside the `DIV.box`, you'll be able to apply any margin or padding to it and it wont break your `DIV.box` percents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of a margin, use transparent or white borders along with `box-sizing` property

```
.box {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1em solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #000;
    float: left;
}
```

doing so, the width defined for `large` (66%) and `small` (33%) boxes will include the border width. Of course change the border colour so as it fits your actual background.

Answer (score 0):

See the [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) property.

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

> The specified width and height (and min/max properties) on this
>   element determine the border box of the element. That is, any padding
>   or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this
>   specified width and height. The content width and height are
>   calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths of the
>   respective sides from the specified 'width' and 'height' properties

But this only works with padding, not margin. Twitter Bootstrap uses padding to add spaces between boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below link.

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/92HXT/600/)

```
.BigBox{ width:40%; height:225px;}
.SmallBox{ width:20%;height:225px;}
.InnerBox{ padding:10px; margin:0px 10px 0px 10px; border:solid 1px #666666;}
```

Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

You're adding a margin to each element so the widths need to be decreased slightly:

```
.small {
    width:26%;
}
.large {
    width:59%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Xpcj/

Comment: This is actually a dirty fix. Try to decrease the size of the window : this doesn't work anymore.